# Lost reputation not showing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

[image]

I logged in today and saw that 15 of my reputation points had vanished. When I opened the reputation tab, I noticed that even though at the top it showed -15, it didn't list exactly where or how my reputation went. Even the reputation counts for today and yesterday show nothing. Is this a bug of some sort?

Comment: Did you expand the "today" arrow? Might be simple unaccept event.

Comment: Expanding the arrow doesn't show anything .. but checking the show removed posts box did. See Lix/ManishEarth's answer below.

Comment: If you'll post what question it is someone with 10K+ rep can see why the answer/question got deleted if you like. :)

Comment: It says here that it was voluntarily removed by the author.

Comment: Weird - you can see the deleted post??

Comment: Nope, can't see the question. Can see the question title in my reputation history after checking the show-removed-posts box. When I click on it, it shows an error page saying "This question was voluntarily removed by its author." Why do you think it to be weird?

Comment: Oh lol, forgot about that! Thought your answer was deleted for some reason that's all. :-)

Comment: @Aki: Can you give a link? (I'm not a mod but maybe I can get one to help)

Comment: I thought you said it was how things were, question gets deleted, you lose rep associated with that question. How can a mod help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably a post got deleted. Scroll down and check the "show removed posts" box.

[image]

If the problem still persists, it's a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Comment: So that means, if a post, with my answer as the accepted answer, get deleted (even voluntarily), I lose my rep for that question?

Comment: @Aki: Yep. ALL upvotes/downvotes/rep is gone. Deleted answers lose their own rep; deleted questions destroy the rep of all answers as well. A deleted question is of the sort that you shouldn't have answered it in the first place (usually)--instead just flagged it for close/delete.

Comment: @Lix thanks for the freehand circle goodness! Cannot do from phone atm :/

Comment: +1 for the "shouldn't have answered it in the first place"

Comment: @Lix another show off - you could start below the 155 you know. :P

Comment: @sha!  You are really on my case today! No FHRC for you! :P

Comment: @Lix: I drag-dropped `FHRC` to a new tab (to Google) a moment before it struck me that it meant `freehand RED circle` (always heard it called FHC).  [Flood Hazard Research Center](http://www.google.com/search?q=FHRC) Who'd want THAT? :P

Comment: @Lix but you got my +1 - show off or not. :)

Comment: but @sha - this is not my post ;)

Comment: @Lix oops! Blonde moment alert!

Comment: @Lix: I ATE YOUR REP BWAHAHAAH

Comment: @man - hahaha - I don't choose the names :P  I just continue the memes ;)