# Reputation has been going down without any downvotes

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did I just lose some reputation without any explanation in my profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133299/why-did-i-just-lose-some-reputation-without-any-explanation-in-my-profile)
>   [Reputations on Stack Overflow deducted - Reason Unknown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135451/reputations-on-stack-overflow-deducted-reason-unknown)

I've noticed this past couple of weeks that my reputation has gone down twice without receiving any down votes. My reputation change history doesn't indicate any losses that I can see either.

I lost about 10 rep about a week ago, and I just lost another 5 rep today. Why would this be happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why did I just lose some reputation without any explanation in my profile?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133299/why-did-i-just-lose-some-reputation-without-any-explanation-in-my-profile) and [Reputations on Stack Overflow deducted - Reason Unknown](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135451/reputations-on-stack-overflow-deducted-reason-unknown) and [Lost reputation not showing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128262/lost-reputation-not-showing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you check the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of your Reputation tab.

You'll see that an answer of yours was deleted and the reputation you got from the votes on it has been removed as well.

For a full list of things that affect reputation, see: [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

Comment: That was it. All this time and I had no idea that checkbox was there.

Comment: This is one of those situations where having to wait to accept an answer could have a negative affect. See, I'm going to forget to accept 10 minutes from now...

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if any of your posts were deleted? This would cause any associated reputation to be removed from your account.

Comment: I don't know. If they were, it wasn't by me. Wouldn't that be indicated in todays rep list?

Answer (score 0):

Reputation can be revoked if, for example, a question you've answered gets deleted or moved to another Stack Exchange site.