# Weird Reputation Change (How do I report)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

On StackOverflow, I just went from a reputation `2,452` to `2,412` in a matter of seconds, no Idea how. Who do i ask and how to I report this to?

## Resolved

A question had been deleted, and that is the reason I lost the reputation.

[Lost reputation not showing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128262/226446)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128262/226446, plus, while this isn't actually a duplicate, it has some good information on why you lose reputation sometimes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80862/226446

Comment: @lnafziger Turns out it was a deleted question.

Comment: This is most likely caused by a deleted post. To see reputation gained/lost with deleted posts, make sure the "show removed posts" option is checked at the bottom of your [reputation page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1786283/enginefree?tab=reputation).

Comment: Figured it was something like that.  I think that "show removed posts" should be checked by default so that people don't wonder when this happens...

Comment: The funny thing is I myself would never ever write a meta post if I went from 2400 to 2500 ;-)

Comment: It was indeed a deleted question - since you've found it now I've closed it as duplicate of the Q that helped you find it. If there was more to it than that feel free to @me for reopening.

Comment: @lnafziger I think they should have functionality to keep the reputation if the question is deleted.

Comment: @Flexo Can I suggest to the developers to add functionality to retain the reputation earned after the question is deleted?

Comment: That will happen in some cases. The question has to be above a given age and the answer must have at least some number of votes (I forget the exact values).

Comment: Well, if a question is deleted, there is usually a good reason for it (it wasn't appropriate for the site, etc).  In this case, we probably shouldn't keep the reputation since it didn't help the site overall.

Comment: @halirutan: I would.  Imagine all of the up-votes you would get for being honest in a situation like that!  ;-)

Comment: 60 days old and a score of 3 or greater @Flexo

Comment: @Bart I had 4, but it was a couple of days old.

Comment: @halirutan http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43621/192187

Comment: [*"Reputation earned for posts with a score of 3 or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days, is retained"*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that). There's a lot of background behind that.

Comment: Thanks Guys. Appreciate it.

Comment: @AmericanLuke It seems I haven't thought that through. Report +70, keep that 70 and gain another 27*5 on meta. I'll reconsider.